# WereFox / Werewolf / FBI / Conspiracy Series

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I'm looking for a series that starts with a female FBI agent that happen to be a werefox and her partner, who's a werewolf. In fact his WHOLE family is in the FBI (or some other government agency). There's a conspiracy that causes her to be injured while in England and the discovery that she may have roots in Asia.

I've been going nuts trying to find books / series I've read over the past few years and I am having a hard time.

The issue is that 1) I read three fiction books a week, and 2) since I am downloading to Kindle or from Hoopla the tactile memories of physically purchasing a novel in a bookstore and holding it in my hands is missing. In fact, I'm surprise at how quickly authors and title leave my memory when the act of making a choice / seeing the books cover on my nightstand and holding it cause the lapse in forming memories.

BTW, if anyone else has noticed this, please let me know.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: I read the all of the published series over the past year. But that is not something to go by. I tend to find a series and if I like it I will read all the published books in one long stretch. But the books themself were probably written in the 2010's forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pulling my (limited) hair out I finally found the series.

"Balancing the Scales" by R.J. Blain.

There are currently two books in the series:
**Karma** (**Balancing the Scales Book 1**) 5/15/2016
**License to Kill** (**Balancing the Scales Book 2**) 12/202/2020

*"Karma Johnson has spent her entire adult life working to become a member of FBI's Child Abduction Rapid Deployment team. She's earned her transfer to CARD, but when she's caught up in the kidnapping of an infant from a festival, she learns what it's like to be the victim. Pretending she's a teen keeps her alive while trying to get herself and the baby to safety."*

My thanks to those that looked.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but could it be [Dead Girls Club](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18039696-dead-girls-club) by Crash Froelich?

[image: Dead Girls Club]

The female protagonist, *Sae*, is a [kitsune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune) not a werefox, but she turns the male protagonist, *Lesley Mann*, into a werefox to save his life after he is attacked by two ghouls. Sae works for the FBI as you say, and Mann joins the FBI after his transformation and becomes the leader of the *Paranormal Weapons and Tactics division*.

I cannot find a copy of the book to check the remaining details. There is [a free sample available on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dead-Girls-Club-Crash-Froelich-ebook/dp/B00D6NLLAQ) but it only includes the opening scenes. However the summaries I've found of the book imply that Mann's family become involved later in the book.

I'm not sure if there is formally a *Dead Girls Club* series, but there are other books involving Sae and Mann e.g. [Tree of Life, Tree of Destiny](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25533785-tree-of-life-tree-of-destiny).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no that is not the series I am looking for. The first book involves her as part of the FBI hostage rescue rescue team where she saves a baby from an organized group of kidnappers.